# How to get a dynamic column name in a PostgreSQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following PostgreSQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  displaylabel VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO test (id, displaylabel) VALUES (1, 'Hello');
INSERT INTO INTO test (id, displaylabel) VALUES (2, 'World');
```

I want to write a SELECT statement that returns the number of rows in the table, with the column name being the current month and year. For example, if today is `2023-10-19`, I want the result to be:

| October 2023 |
| --- |
| 2 |

I tried the following SELECT statements, but they don't work:

```
SELECT 
    id AS format('%s %s', to_char(current_date, 'Month'), to_char(current_date, 'YYYY')) 
FROM test;

SELECT id AS (
  to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month') || ' ' || to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY')
)
FROM test;
```

I get the following error messages:

```
Query Error: error: syntax error at or near "("
```

I need to use only SELECT statements because my account is read-only, so I can't use EXECUTE.

How can I write a SELECT statement that returns the desired result, with a dynamic column name?

Example output:

| October 2023 |
| --- |
| 2 |

DB fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Hs1YtQxHfJMeKviNrj9Rb/0

Comment: Why are you doing this? This isn't what SQL is meant for... Things like custom column-names, pivots/unpivots, et cetera should be performed by your presentation-layer, not in SQL.

Comment: Why do you want that to be the column name? You can `select 'October 2023' as column_name, count(*) as count_ from test;` - data goes into rows, vertially, not horizontally into columns. If you later wanted to do `select "October 2023" from t1;`, it should be `select count_ from t1 where column_name="October 2023";`.